# Getting data in between two strings in Python2.7

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, function-parameter

I am trying to get the data in between two strings from a text file containing data like :

```
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_FPS_List
commands 1 :SensorFps ( 30.000)
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Switchview
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Set
commands 2 :SetExIndex (12), SetExIndex (13), EiSwitchAssign (1, 13)
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Switchview
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen
X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
X_0_Gui_Menu_100_Menu_Recording
commands 3 :MediaCodec (4), SetSensorFormat (0)
X_0_Gui_Menu_110_Menu_Recording_Project
commands 4 :ProjectFps (0), SensorFps ( 23.976)
X_0_Gui_Menu_100_Menu_Recording
X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
X_0_Gui_Menu_300_Menu_Outputs
X_0_Gui_Menu_310_Menu_Outputs_EVF_mon
commands 5 :ZoomPos (0)
X_0_Gui_Menu_312_Menu_Outputs_EVF_exptools
commands 6 :ExposureToolSel (0, 1), ExposureToolSel (1, 1), ZebraMode (0, 0), ZebraMode (1, 0)
X_0_Gui_Menu_310_Menu_Outputs_EVF_mon
X_0_Gui_Menu_317_Menu_Outputs_EVF_settings
X_0_Gui_Menu_310_Menu_Outputs_EVF_mon
X_0_Gui_Menu_311_Menu_Outputs_EVF_overlays
commands 7 :CenterMark (0, 1)
```

I want to get an output like:

```
Navigated pages 1:
                  X_0_Gui_Homescreen_FPS_List
Navigated pages 2:
                  X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen
                     X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Switchview
                        X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Set
Navigated pages 3:
                  X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Switchview
                     X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen
                        X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
                           X_0_Gui_Menu_100_Menu_Recording
```

and so on... (Data before commands 1 should go into `Navigated pages 1` and data between command 2 and 1 should go into `Navigated pages 2` and so on)

Code done till now:

```
def get_navigated_path(command_number):
    navigated_and_commands = open('navigated_and_commands','r')
    data = navigated_and_commands.read()
    block = ""
    for i in range(0,command_number):
        block = re.compile(ur'commands ' + str(i) + ' :' + '[\S ]+\s((?:(?![^\n]+commands ' + str(i+1) + ' :' + ').)*)', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
    data_with_block=re.findall(block, data)
    for line in data_with_block:
        if "X_" in line:
            print "       > navigated pages: \n" + "                         " + line
```

Which produces almost the required output also with

```
       > navigated pages: 
                         X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Switchview
X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Set
commands 2 :SetExIndex (12), SetExIndex (13), EiSwitchAssign (1, 13)
```

I don't need the line `commands 2 :SetExIndex (12), SetExIndex (13), EiSwitchAssign (1, 13)`
 and also I want it to be organised like this

```
   > navigated pages: 
                     X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen
                        X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Switchview
                           X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Set
```

Any guidance would be really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I won't use regular expressions... may be a simple iteration can fit the case:

```
def get_navigated_path(command_number):
    navigated_and_commands = open('navigated_and_commands','r')
    i = 0
    for line in navigated_and_commands.readlines():
        if line.startswith("commands %d"%command_number):
            break
        if line.startswith("commands"):
            i += 1
            print "Navigated pages %d"%i
            continue
        print line
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have edited my question again to make it better understandable. The problem here is this function is used inside another function which does the looping. I need only one `Navigated pages ` at one function call not all the navigated pages. For example one first function call I need `Navigated pages 1:
                  X_0_Gui_Homescreen_FPS_List` and on second call I need `Navigated pages 2:
                  X_0_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen
                     X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Switchview
                        X_0_Gui_Homescreen_EI_Set` and so on..

Comment: Each call will read the file again and again, which may be heavy load. Wouldn't it be better if you parse the file once and store navigation tokens in a list?